# create array of objects which have constructor function

Tags: java

i have this class

```
public class customer {

    int id;
    int status ;
    customer(int value)
    {

        id = value;
        status = 0;

    }
}
```

i want to create an array consist of 100 objects of customer.
how can i pass argument to constractor function of customer class ?

```
public class barbershop {
    Queue WaitSeat ;
    Queue WaitRoom ;
    static barber [] bb ;
    static customer [] cc;
    barbershop(){
        WaitSeat = new PriorityQueue(4);
        WaitRoom = new PriorityQueue(13);
        bb = new barber[3];
        cc = new customer [100]{1}; // problem !

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Create objects within a loop and place them in the array

You need to create each object individually, then place it in the array. These are two seperate operations (although they can be within the same line). A loop will make this far more pleasent.

```
cc = new customer[100];
for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
    cc[i]=new customer(1);
}
```

## Its the same for objects with no-argument constructors

Although the compiler did not complain I do not believe `bb = new barber[3];` does what you think it does. It creates an array large enough to fit 3 references to a `Barber` object. But it doesn't create those objects, only the the array. At this point `bb` contains `{null, null, null}` so you would need to use a similar loop to fill `bb` with `Barber` objects.

## Java naming convention

It is also convention to use UpperCamelCase for class names. So `customer` should be `Customer` and `barber` should be `Barber`. Equally variable names should be lowerCamelCase so `WaitSeat` should be `waitSeat` and `WaitRoom` should be `waitRoom`.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse `array` initialization with object initialization.

`cc` is an `array` of `Customer` (note, capitalized here).

In order to access the constructor of `Customer` and get an instance you would need to populate your `array` with instances.

To simplify your issue you can do:

```
  cc = new Customer[100];
  Arrays.fill(cc, new Customer(1));
```

This will fill your 100-sized `array` with 100 elements referencing one instance of `Customer` whose `id` will be `1`.

Word of caution, the instance is shared across 100 elements.

In turn, if you modify one element you "modify the whole array", as shown below.

**Self-contained example**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initializing array
        Customer[] cc = new Customer[100];
        // filling array
        Arrays.fill(cc, new Customer(1));
        // printing array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cc));
        // changing any array element
        cc[0].setId(2);
        // printing array again
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cc));
    }

    static class Customer {
        int id;
        int status;

        Customer(int value) {
            id = value;
            status = 0;
        }
        // invoking this method on any object of the array will update all references
        public void setId(int value) {
            id = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Customer %d", id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, Customer 1, etc...]

[Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, Customer 2, etc...]
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative.  Would it be fair to say that this fills the array with references to the same object. Which may well be what the OP wants, but could be dangerous for mutable objects

Comment: @RichardTingle thanks for your comment - I actually realized the wording in my answer was very ambiguous: it's not 100 instances but of course 100 references to 1 instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cc = new customer [100]
```

This will create a ref `cc` holding the `100 Customer refs`.

```
for(int i=0;i>cc.length;i++){
    cc[i]=new customer(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class barbershop {
    Queue WaitSeat ;
    Queue WaitRoom ;
    static barber [] bb ;
    static customer [] cc;
    barbershop(){
        WaitSeat = new PriorityQueue(4);
        WaitRoom = new PriorityQueue(13);
        bb = new barber[3];

        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
          cc[i] = new customer (i); 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would say that [braceless loops are very dangerous beasts](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/); prone to later bugs when the code is modified

Comment: Ok.Added that too.Thanks.

Comment: Much nicer. One final thing; you've left out the `cc = new customer[100]` line, and assuming you stick with an array size of 100 your loop should be `for(i=0;i<100;i++)` because java arrays are zero indexed

Answer (score 0):

First, classes should always be written in CamelCase.
Second, I don't think that's possible. You coudl use a for loop like this:

```
cc = new Customer[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cc[i] = new Customer(i);
}
```